# website redirected you too many times

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean

I have a webiste [onlinefeepayment](https://onlinefeepayment.in/), which was working fine. But suddenly from yesterday it shows

```
The onlinefeepayment.in page isn’t working

onlinefeepayment.in redirected you too many times.
```

in chrome and

```
The page isn't redirecting properly
```

in firefox. I have no idea whats going on ! Please help me regarding the matter

Comment: Could you please add some more informations? You already tag your post as `.htaccess` related so why don't you put this file?

Comment: Did you recently make any changes in the virtual host or .htaccess file related to redirection? Likely from HTTP to HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you have a problem with your `.htaccess` file. I had a similar problem and I resolved my issue with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```